# Using Jest, how can I check that an argument to a mocked function is a function?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm trying this:

```
expect(AP.require).toBeCalledWith('messages', () => {})
```

where AP.require is a mocked function that should receive a string and a function as the second argument.

Test fails with the message:

```
Expected mock function to have been called with:
  [Function anonymous] as argument 2, but it was called with [Function anonymous]
```

Answer (score 112):

To assert any function, you can you use [`expect.any(constructor)`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectanyconstructor):

So with your example it would be like this:

```
expect(AP.require).toBeCalledWith('messages', expect.any(Function))
```

Comment: Probably obvious for some, but still worth pointing out you can use any other constructor (e.g. `Number`, `Object`, etc.)

Comment: There is also `expect.anything()` if that second argument is optional.

Comment: @Rohmer If that second argument is optional, you should probably add an additional test.

Answer (score 24):

The problem is that a function is an object and comparing objects in JavaScript will fail if they are not the same instance

```
() => 'test' !== () => 'test'
```

To solve this you can use [`mock.calls`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockcalls) to check the parameters seperataly

```
const call = AP.require.mock.calls[0] // will give you the first call to the mock
expect(call[0]).toBe('message')
expect(typeof call[1]).toBe('function')
```

Comment: This answer helped me, thanks Andreas. I think the first line should be `const call = AP.require.mock.calls[0]`